# Jenkins DSL job pass a variable to github class?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to use a loop to seed jenkinsfiles jobs from diff repos in an org, so I was wondering if this is valid:

```
services.each { service, option ->
....
....
            definition {
            cpsScm {
                scriptPath(jenkinspath + "/" + "Jenkinsfile")
                scm {
                    git {
                        branch('master')
                        remote {
                          github('MyOrg/'${repo}, 'https', 'github.com')
                          credentials('my-ro-token')

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried with $repo, repo,  ${repo}, "$repo" '${repo}', and more, and nothing works. I could not find any place if that is even possible, de documentation says just this:

```
 github(String ownerAndProject, String branch = null, String protocol = 'https', String host = 'github.com', Closure closure = null)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Ah! seems the whole org+repo needs to be in the same variable:                           Rather than github('MyOrg/'repo, 'https', 'github.com'), should be: github(repo, 'https', 'github.com')

Answer (score 0):

Nerver mind, it works as the other env variables on DSL jobs.

```
def repourl = "myorg/myrepo"
def myrepo = "somerepo"
...
     github(repourl, 'https', 'github.com')
    or
     github('myorg' + '/' + myrepo, 'https', 'github.com')
```